# Request data in Node.js from AngularJS without bodyParser

Tags: node.js, request, angularjs, express

In my app I need to use body parser to request params (Node.js AngularJS based on [angular-express-blog](https://github.com/btford/angular-express-blog)). For example (AngularJS controller):

```
$scope.changeComment = (comment) ->
  $http.put('/api/post/' + $routeParams.id + '/editComment/' + comment._id, $scope.comment).success (data) ->
    $scope.post = data.post
```

So according to AngularJS docs `$http.post('/someUrl', data).success(successCallback);`

But I dont know how to found this data in node.js express. I can only use bodyParser, that parse only data in form.

```
app.put '/api/post/:id/editComment/:cid' = (req, res) ->
  id = req.params.id;
  cid = req.params.cid;
  console.log req
  Post.findById id, (err, post) ->
    unless err
      comment = post.comments.id(cid)
      console.log req.body
      comment.text = req.body.text
      post.save (err1) ->
```

So how can I transmit and grab data?

app.cofiguration:

```
app.configure "development", ->
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  app.use express.static(__dirname + '/public')
  app.use express.errorHandler(
    dumpExceptions: true
    showStack: true
  )
```

And view file https://gist.github.com/3189377

Comment: You're using express, right?  Can I see your app.configure() block?  It should just work, with req.body being the data sent by $http.

Comment: I updated post with this info and find out that `$scope.comment` should be `comment`, and it works now. Thanks for that!:)

Comment: I tried it before but I guess i didn't restart server or smth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error `$scope.comment` should be just `comment`:

```
$scope.changeComment = (comment) ->
  $http.put('/api/post/' + $routeParams.id + '/editComment/' + comment._id, comment).success (data) ->
    $scope.post = data.post
```